# Getting, TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, when I'm trying to add a new element on a list

Tags: python

```
list_personagens = []

nomeA = input("Insert the name\n")
papel_personagem1 = random.randint(0, 1)
personagem1 = People(nomeA, papel_personagem1)
list_personagens.append(papel_personagem1())
print()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    lista_personagens.append(papel_personagem1())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm trying to add a randomly generated int to the empty list I just created, however, it gives an error saying that the 'int' object is not callable.

EDIT: Found the error. i was calling papel_personagem1 as a fuction.

Comment: `papel_personagem1` is the return value of `People(...)`, and you are calling it. What is `papel_personagem1`?

Comment: Also, please include the *full traceback* so we can see what line is causing this. Without it all we can do is guess. Show what `People` returns too, unless that line is never reached.

Comment: You could have assigned an integer to `input` for example, also giving you that error message.

Comment: You need to retrieve `()` in `append` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty descriptive - you are trying to call it.

Try this (without a pair of parenthesis):

`list_personagens.append(papel_personagem1)`

Answer (score 1):

`papel_personagem1()` is treating `papel_personagem1` as a function (calling it) when it's not, you should remove the parentheses in order to treat it like an int:

```
papel_personagem1 = random.randint(0, 1) # an int
list_personagens.append(papel_personagem1)
```